# how can i change include path in php.ini file

Tags: apache, php

my php.ini(C:\php) file include path

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;C:\php\extras;C:\php\extras\doctrine-dbal"
```

but phpinfo() look as   include_path =.;C:\php\pear

how can i change include path as include_path = ".;C:\php\extras;C:\php\extras\doctrine-dbal"

i'm sure there ara no more php.ini file and my apache web server were restart

when i view include path using

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure to restart apache and php when you change php.ini btw.

Comment: yes sure i were restart apache server

Comment: how do you restart php?

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the value in your `php.ini` configuration file or you can use the [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) function at runtime.  There may be various versions of `php.ini` configuration files on your system/server.  Refer to you `phpinfo()` output for what location is being used for your instance.

Your location appears to be `C:\php\php.ini` per the `Loaded Configuration File` directive so you would want to modify that version.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://php.net/include-path
```

Comment: i know but i want to change in the php.ini file. when i change that not effected in phpinfo()

Comment: yes i restarted, but nothing change in my include path (is there any module need to enable in apache server)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are looking at the right `php.ini`.

Besides that, you could set the include path in you code by using [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) function.

Comment: i'll post complete phpinfo() in that show to me Loaded Configuration File in the C:\php\php.ini location